# Is Blockchain a single linked list?

Tags: list, data-structures, types, blockchain

Seen as datatype, is Blockchain a single linked list? As each block refers to the previous block using a hash.
Or is it some kind of tree?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way a blockchain is represented as a singly linked list. Each block has a hash of the previous block which can be thought of as a pointer to previous block.

Some differences are that in a linked list, there are generally more operations for a linked list that are not available in a blockchain, most notably being able to remove a block and to add a block in the middle of the list/chain.

In the bitcoin blockchain, and probably others, each transaction in the block is stored in a [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). The blockchain is not a tree.

Comment: How can I get previous block from hash of previous block's data? In linked list we have pointer of next node which can lead to the that node but how is that possible with block which contains hash of previous block's data?